# Manually Disable Folder Redirection Sync Over Slow Connection

Tags: windows

I have a manager laptop set up with folder redirection / offline files to enable online/offline use. Currently the manager is complaining of very slow file operations when she uses it from home. She has a router-based VPN connection to the office from home. I'm reasonable certain that the slow file operations ("copying photos from my camera") are due to the fact that the Redirected My Documents and Desktop folders are keeping in sync with the server, despite the slow connection.

Most of the time, I would like to keep her connected/online. But I would like to provide an option to disconnect to improve the speed, when she's remote. Is there a way of manually going offline in Vista with the redirected photos (other than disconnecting the from the internet)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSCCMD tool to force offline mode in a particular share, for example:

```
CSCCMD /DISCONNECT: \\MyServer\MyShare
```

So you could use this to create a batch file that the user can click to enble offline mode when on a slow connection.

CSSCMD v1.1 is available from MS, but its one of those fixes you have to call and request, for some reason, full detail is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884739). CSSCMD v1.0 is included in Server 2003 support tools, so may be worth trying that version first.

Comment: This is the most appropriate solution IMO. A desktop shortcut for this labelled something like 'Work Offline'. Maybe a second one to come online again.

There is a GPO setting for 'slow link detection' that can control whether the offline or online file stores are used, but it has a reputation for being quite unpredictable.

Relevant KB articles here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/227369
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811525